# Set Range method fails

Tags: excel, vba, set, range

This seems like  a very simple problem. The following macro fails on the line:
*Set RngS = wsS.Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(21, 13))*
Error 1004: "Method 'range of object'_Worksheet failed."

Thoughts? Thank you.

```
Sub CreateSummaryNew()
Dim Pn, As Integer
Dim RngP, RngS As Range
Dim wsP, wsS As Worksheet

Pn = ActiveSheet.Range("G3")
Set wsP = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Pn)
Set wsS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Pn + 30)

Set RngP = wsP.Range(Cells(8, 31), Cells(21, 43))
Set RngS = wsS.Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(21, 13))
RngP.Copy (RngS.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues))

End Sub
```

Comment: qualify `cells` with a worksheet

Comment: Also, in this line `Dim RngP, RngS As Range` only `RngS` is a Range, `RngP` is of type Variant

Comment: Is the code located In the same workbook containing the worksheets `Worksheets(Pn)` and `Worksheets(Pn+30)` and what are their names? Is `ActiveSheet` in the same workbook? What is the tab name or the index of `Activesheet`?